# How do you use mongodb native, express and body-parser to post request and save data?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, post, body-parser

I have been trying to save data to a mongodb database but nothing I do seems to work. the first error i'm getting is related to the `req.body`

When I click the submit button, `console.log(req.body)` returns

```
[Object: null prototype] { name: 'John', priority: 'go to bed' }
```

rather than

```
{ name: 'John', priority: 'go to bed' }
```

Secondly, I don't know if I'm saving the data to the database correctly because I have seen so many different ways of doing it that I'm confused

The relevant line of code

```
db.collection.insertOne(req.body);
```

and relevant error:

```
TypeError: db.createCollection is not a function
```

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });

const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connection URL
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";

app.listen(7000);


app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})

app.post('/todo',urlencodedParser,function(req, res){

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, function(err,db){
        if(err) throw err;
        console.log('Databese created!');
        db.collection.insertOne(req.body);
        db.close();
    });
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        I am an index page.

        <form class="" action="/todo" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="todo">
            <input type="text" name="priority" placeholder="priority">
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: YOu should add this two line `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.use(bodyParser.json())` because you're sending data in json.

Comment: That solved my first problem thank you.

Comment: Regarding second problem you need to pass collection name  like this `dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(myobj,` in query and db name in connection string `"mongodb://localhost:27017/dbName"`

Comment: I changed it to `db.collection('data').insertOne(req.body);` but is still get the error `TypeError: db.collection is not a function`

Comment: check my answer and try that code

Comment: This is what I did, `const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/DataBaseName";` and  `dbo.collection('data').insertOne(req.body);` and got `ReferenceError: dbo is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regarding first error**, You should add this two line to get json data as a request object because you're sending data in json

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true})) 
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

**Regarding second query:**
Inserting record in mongoDB

```
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
      if (err) throw err;
      var dbo = db.db("mydb");
      var myobj = { name: "Company Inc", address: "Highway 37" };
      dbo.collection("customers").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("1 document inserted");
        db.close();
      });
    });
```

Comment: I copied this exactly but i'm still getting the save dbo is not defined error :(

Comment: Can you please explain this like ` var dbo = db.db("mydb");` in your answer?

Comment: change mydb as per your DB name and try

Comment: @Simple It'll listen to given DB for operations

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you don't specify to your MongoDB Instance which database you are using.

```
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/myDataBaseName";
```

This should solve this out for you.